# How can I collect repeated contact entries under one call log entry?

Tags: calls

I'm running Cyanogen 5.0.8 and previously had stock 1.2 before this. On both releases I'd like is to be able to able to collect repeated call log entries in only one single entry reflecting last activity, whether it is "received", "missed", or "dialed". When the entry is to be tapped all activities related to the contact would be shown.

Is any one familiar with such feature and how can I achieve it on my phone?

Comment: This feature is available on CM6.  Is it possible for you to upgrade?

Comment: It is possible of course. But I don't want to. But thanks, I didn't know that.

Comment: Yeah, CM6 will group your call log together of repeated calls in a row into one entry that you can expand.  I believe it is a Android 2.2 feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CyanogenMod 6 does this feature because it is native to Android 2.2.  [See this CyanogenMod issue report for more details](http://code.google.com/p/cyanogenmod/issues/detail?id=1349).

Comment: I just installed CM6 on my Dream. It is pretty amazing. It has that feature and many more. More important, it is a lot smother on my phone than CM5.0.8.
Upgrade process went smoothly with pre-installed apps intact and no change to my settings.

Comment: 6.1 will be out soon :)  They usually recommend a wipe and reload for upgrades, so if you encounter any problems with CM6, I'd try that first.  You can backup all apps and their data with Titanium backup.